# How to save state on service restart? Save data on DriverUnload and retrieve it in DriverEntry

Tags: windows, kernel, wdk

In a kernel mode windows driver, how can I store data on somewhere on the OS in DriverUnload routine and retrieve the data on the DriverEntry?

What I want to do is keep some variables across service restarts (not on OS restarts but on service restarts). So I can compile & test my service quickly without configuring every time i reload it. (For development purposes only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical approach is to store your values in the registry key specific to your driver in the Registry. When your DriverEntry runs, the registry path will be given to the function. For more information, here are some of the articles that should be useful to you:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544262(v=vs.85).aspx.  Introduction to Registry Keys for Drivers.
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544113(v=vs.85).aspx  See the information regarding the RegistryPath argument of DriverEntry function.

Comment: Thanks. But I was excepting somewhere to store a pointer to a struct. By this way, the data would reset on system restart but kept on service restart. And I wouldn't expose the data to user and bother reading / writing to registry, I'll mark it correct after a while if I wouldn't find a better way (from my perspective) to do this. P.S. much thanks for the response

Comment: Glad that it helps. Please mark the question as answered for the benefit of the others.

Comment: I just thought I could find a different solution (like storing pointer to a struct somewhere in the OS), therefore waited another answer.